# QML AppSwitch sending onCheckedChanged signal each time page is opened?

Tags: qml, signals, toggle, v-play, felgo

I have an `AppSwitch`, which is being used to 'activate/deactivate' user accounts in my app, It's checked status is read from a database, which works as intended, changing both the switch and text depending on the bool per user.

**My problem is**
Each time I open the page with the `AppSwitch` on, it sends the `onCheckedChanged` signal - in turn sending a notification to the user their account has been activated? I had planned to notify users that their account was active with a push notification, but don't want this sending every time the admin moves to their page!

I am using Felgo(formerly V-Play) for development, a link to the `AppSwitch` documentation is:
[Felgo AppSwitch](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-appswitch/)

My code is:

```
            Rectangle {               
                width: parent.width / 2
                height: parent.height
                Column {
                    id: column
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    AppButton {
                        id: groupStatusText
                        width: parent.width
                        height: parent.height / 2
                    }
                    AppSwitch {
                        id: editStatus
                        knobColorOn: "#b0ced9"
                        backgroundColorOn: "#81b1c2"
                        checked: {
//userListItem is the current profile details of the user page
                            if(userListItem.groupStatus === 1) {
                                groupStatusText.text = "Deactivate this user"
                            }
                            else if(userListItem.groupStatus === 0) {
                                groupStatusText.text = "Activate this user"
                            }
                        }
                        onCheckedChanged: {
                            if(editStatus.checked === true) {
//the signal which sends to my database on updating the value,
//works as intended but sends signal each time page is created?
                                detailPage.adminEditGroupStatus(1)
                            } else {
                                detailPage.adminEditGroupStatus(0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Is it normal behaviour for the `onCheckedChanged` signal to be firing on each instance the page is loaded? or how could I amend this that it only fires when the user changes it!?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is `AppSwitch`?

Comment: Hi @folibis I have updated my question with a link to Felgo's `AppSwitch` qml type, it's a toggle on/off switch used for simple bool functions most commonly used!

Comment: The property @checked@ should be true or false, I suppose. Why are you executing that code on that property? What that code returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to be sure the signal is sent after full init of the component (including after creation of the binding on the `checked` property).

You can add a boolean property on the switch :

```
AppSwitch {
    property bool loaded: false    

    Component.onCompleted: loaded = true

    onCheckedChanged: {
        if (loaded) {
            // notify user
        }
    }
}
```

or simply use the `state`:

```
AppSwitch {    
    Component.onCompleted: state = "loaded"

    onCheckedChanged: {
        if (state === "loaded") {
            // notify user
        }
    }
}
```